# Unit Testing Exceptions in Dart/Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter-test

I'm trying to unit test using the given code.

```
test('Given Employee When employeeName less than 5 then throws Exception', () async {
    final employee = EmployeesCompanion.insert(
        employeeName: 'Tony',
        employeeCode: 'HR-121',
        address: '5th Floor, Park Avenue',
        contact: '1234567890',
        hiringDate: DateTime.now());
    expectLater(await employeesDB.createEmployee(employee),
        throwsA((f) => f.toString().contains('employeeName: Must at least be 5 characters long')));
  });
```

My unit test includes a predicate `throwsA((f) => f.toString().contains('employeeName: Must at least be 5 characters long'))` as given but dart fails this test with the exception:

```
package:moor/src/runtime/data_verification.dart 74:5                  VerificationContext.throwIfInvalid
package:moor/src/runtime/query_builder/statements/insert.dart 197:51  InsertStatement._validateIntegrity
package:moor/src/runtime/query_builder/statements/insert.dart 96:5    InsertStatement.createContext
package:moor/src/runtime/query_builder/statements/insert.dart 64:17   InsertStatement.insert
package:moor_ex/src/db/employees.dart 79:76                           EmployeesDB.createEmployee
test\employee_dept_test.dart 28:35                                    main.<fn>

InvalidDataException: Sorry, EmployeesCompanion(id: Value.absent(), employeeName: Value(Tony), employeeCode: Value(HR-121), address: Value(5th Floor, Park Avenue), contact: Value(1234567890), hiringDate: Value(2020-08-18 13:26:34.435349)) cannot be used for that because: 
• employeeName: Must at least be 5 characters long.
```

So what's the correct way to write this test in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `await`, or move it outside/before the `expectLater`.

The only difference between `expect` and [`expectLater`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/expectLater.html) is that the latter returns a future, but you ignore that future.

The `expect`/`throwsA` needs either a closure or a `Future` as the actual value, but you `await` that future so the `await ...` expression throws before you even call `expectLater`. Remove the `await` so you pass the `Future` to `expectLater` and the [`throwsA`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/test_api/throwsA.html) will then catch and match the error of that future.

So, I recommend changing it to:

```dart
  await expectLater(employeesDB.createEmployee(employee), ...
```